# How does the User's input meet the requirements chosen?

Tags: string, if-statement, variables, user-input, uppercase

So, I want the code to see the user's input and meet the requirements of my choice. Let's say I want the user to input a password, but it must be 8 letters long or higher and have one letter in Capital letters.

Let's say I want the user to input a password, but it must have one letter in Capital letters.

```
password = input("What is your password?: ")
if password == (password.upper = 1)
```

Does this work or is does it have to be more specific. I hope you can help. Thank You!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using python

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. `upper()` is a method that converts the `str` to uppercase. You need a method called `isupper()`, but that checks if the whole string is uppercase. One way is to simply loop over the characters.

```py
password = input("What is your password?: ")
valid = False
if len(password) >= 8:
    for c in password:
        if c.isupper():
            valid = True
            break
```

This will also work:

```py
valid = len(password) >= 8 and any([c.isupper() for c in password])
```

When in doubt, refer to your teaching material or the [documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/)

PS Tag your question with the language you use next time.

Comment: So how would you make the program ask for the user's input again?

Comment: Please refer to a tutorial. This site is for asking specific questions, not to teach you the basics. Take a moment to take the [tour] of this website.